# Как объяснить ошибки такого типа?

Tags: фонетика, диалекты

В книге А. В. Текучева "Преподавание русского языка в диалектных условиях" приведен пример из практики одного из учителей Грязовецкой средней школы Вологодской области:

Урок географии:
*Ученик.* Физ. география изучает животных, ростительность, море, горы...
*Учитель.* Растительность. Повтори.
*Ученик.* Изучает растительность, где что ростёт. Южная меснось — ростут пальмы.
*Учитель.* Я же тебя поправила: раастут, раастёт, раастение.
*Ученик.* Растут пальмы. Это на юге, а на севере другая ростительность: сосны, ели, пихты.

Так вот, в задании просят найти диалектизмы и объяснить их, а также ответить на вопрос "В чем автор видит причины ошибок такого типа?".

Диалектизмы, которые я нашел: меснось — тут утрата конечного [т'] в сочетании [cт'].
Ростительность, ростут, ростёт — это тоже диалектизмы? Тогда как их объяснить? Это же окающий говор северного наречия, и в нем на месте предударного [а] должно произноситься [а], типа как тр[а]ва, а не тр[о]ва.
А какие причины может видеть автор в ошибках такого типа? Я эту книжку найти не могу.

Answer (score 1):

> Это же окающий говор северного наречия, и в нем на месте предударного
>   [а] должно произноситься [а], типа как тр[а]ва, а не тр[о]ва.

Кто ж вам так объяснил? Всё наоборот. Оканье - это как раз произнесение **О** на месте орфографического А. А то что вы написали - это аканье. Это - "на пальцах", на самом деле там всё чуть сложнее (по ссылке ниже найдете более точные, "несимметричные" формулировки), но нам достаточно и такого определения.

Я не большой специалист по говорам, но точно могу сказать, что северным говорам в целом аканье как раз не свойственно. Вот первое что попалось на эту тему.
http://slovarfilologa.ru/130/
(там опечатки есть, но в целом все толково написано, без академизмов)

Другой вопрос, есть ли там оканье в чистом виде - в конкретном говоре конкретной местности... Возможно, что и нет. 
Но тут интересный момент,  корень с известным чередованием рост-раст. Помнится, по некоторым данным именно в таких случаях оканье проявляется наиболее сильно. Вряд ли в вашем задании имелось в виду такое объяснение, но, возможно, составитель выбрал этот пример именно из-за его наиболее ярко выраженного О - без глубокого анализа причин.

Answer (score 1):

Я из Вологды. Оканье, особенно в районах, здесь развито сильно, даже проникает в орфографию. Не раз получал документы с резолюцией "оплочено" (вместо "оплачено"), а в центре города, через дорогу от здания где учат учителей русского языка и литературы стоит магазин "Ростишка".

Так что, да, ошибки подобного типа - это как раз влияние северусского наречия.